# Creating arrows based on GPS velocities to show displacement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, gps

I am having trouble creating symbology in ArcGIS that can show velocity arrows of GPS stations. I have a point file with location information, velocity and direction of each GPS station. I want to create a map similar to the image I have attached. The size of the arrows stay the same but the length changes based on the velocity.  See below.

[image]

My first instinct was to use graduated symbols however that just scales the arrows and does not stretch them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think your best bet is presenting data by lines.

- Create any size buffer around points
- Convert them to lines

Apply following field calculator expression (Python) on Shape field:

```
def plineM (B,V,SCALE,shp):
 b=float(B);v=float(V)
 part=shp.getPart(0)
 buf=arcpy.Polygon(part)
 pC=buf.centroid
 X=pC.X+v*SCALE*math.cos(b/180*3.141593)
 Y=pC.Y+v*SCALE*math.sin(b/180*3.141593)
 newP=arcpy.Point(X,Y)
 pLine=arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([pC,newP]))
 return pLine
```

## ----------------------------

```
plineM( !BEARING!, !Velocity!,0.5, !Shape! )
```

Making sure your bearings expressed in degrees, counter clockwise from East

INPUT POINTS TABLE:

[image]

OUTPUT:

[image]

You might want to play with scale factor. Note it is tested on shapefile, if it is not the case start editing session on lines before running expression.

UPDATE: January 2020

A couple of people reported ERROR 000539 when using suggested expression. Vey likely reason is large buffer around original point, resulting in buffer overlaps. If you are using build-in ArcGIS tool to convert buffers to lines it might result in lines made of 2 vertices:

[image]

Possible workaround is making smaller buffers.

Comment: Great answer. Definitely lines are the way to go here.

Comment: With such things, client is rarely satisfied though, because some lines are "missing". To handle this I sometimes apply logarithmic scaling of V.

Comment: This will work for small areas, but can't be scaled up indefinitely.  If you run that script in a projected  if your input bearing is pointing north, the resulting arrow will point "up"

Comment: Where do you think it should point?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to edit comment but posted. Depending on the projection this could be problematic. If you're running this in a projected environment and the bearing is 90, then the arrow produced will be pointing straight up, which may or may not be north on that map/projection.   If you get around this by doing running the script in a lat/long environment, then import the arrows to a projected map, the angles will be right but the lengths will be distorted.  For mapping small areas the distortion might be negligible.  For a continent it would be significant, depending on the projection.

Comment: I badly want to hope for difference between true/projection Norths being researcher main issue

Comment: I'm a cartographer.  I struggled with this problem a year ago.  Your solution works for a map of a small area where north is up.  If used with the wrong projection or extent it could mislead the map reader.

Comment: Hi FelixIP Thank you for taking the time to help me with my problem. I got sent to do some field work and have not had time to try out your solution. Your way seem to be the way to go however I am having some trouble getting it to work. I have your script set up for a test file I created. But I get an error 000539: Error running expression plineM(254,3,0.5,GPVARIANTOJECTO). Any additional help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Can be anything. You have to work in projected coordinate system. Set environments extent to union of inputs. If fails, go to result window and rerun. It should tell the line where it failed. Did you read answer carefully? Is it shapefile?

Comment: Do you run the mentioned python script in field calculator on the "Shape" field of the Line feature class you create on step 2?

Comment: Yes, I did, otherwise why point 2 in the post? Another approach is compute end coordinates using same formulas in polygons table and use xy to line tool.

Comment: The script is failing for me:  ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in plineM
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 90, in _get
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(getattr(self._arc_object, attr_name))
SystemError: <built-in function getattr> returned NULL without setting an error
 Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Comment: Read above comments. If this doesn't work, convert to a true script. Arcgis calculator, can be unpredictable, to say a least.

Comment: @JGIS see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Felix. The script now runs and creates lines, however, they all run parallel from east to west, so the bearing part is not functioning correctly.

Comment: I see 2 possible reasons: a) your PC doesn't know what sine is, unlikely b) you didn't read my post and expressed angles in something else, but degrees. Highly likely.

Comment: My bearings are in arithmetic degrees

Comment: Something mysterious, I am giving up.

Comment: I tried again today and it works perfectly now. I didn't do anything different except changed the scale value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

FelixIP has provided quite an elegant solution. A more simple alternative would be:

1. Set the Symbology for your point layer to "Graduated Symbols", with the Value set to your VELOCITY field.
2. Click the Template button to select a symbol which would be suitable for depicting bearings and velocities - I chose an arrow from the ESRI North font for the example.
3. Set the Symbol Size range to some values which will work for your map (you can refine these values later).
4. Click the Advanced button and select the "Rotation" option. In the Rotate window, select the Bearing field from the drop-down box, and choose the rotation style to suit your data.

(1)

[image: Step 1]

(2)

[image: Step 2]

(4)

[image: Step 3]

(Example result)

[image: Step 4]

Comment: I should have pointed out that these symbols will be centred on where the point is located. This can be changed so that the starting point of the arrow is located at the GPS point by changing the Y offset of the pointer symbol in step 2 so that the base of the arrow is level with the X axis of the preview. If necessary, you could also add a point layer to the symbol to show the GPS point.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However I was looking for a solution where the length of arrow would change based on the velocity, not just scale the size of the arrow.