# Converting radians to arithmetic degrees

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, angles

I need to convert angles that are in radians from Due east to arithmetic degrees for
[Creating arrows based on GPS velocities to show displacement](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218229/creating-arrows-based-on-gps-velocities-to-show-displacement)

The Radians definition for my data is:

[image]

Degrees definition:

[image]

I tried using "degrees = !radians! * 180 / math.pi" in field calculalotr

But this gives negative values which are no higher than -/+ 180

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe this Python Function will be useful to some.

```
def UnitCircleRadiansToTrueNorthAzimuth(theta):
'''Converts Radians (East = 0 then counter-clockwise)
    to Geographic Degrees (North = 0 then clockwise).'''
    import math
    theta = math.degrees(theta)
    theta = theta - 90.0
    if theta < 0:
        theta = theta + 360.0
    theta = -1*(theta * 2 * math.pi / 360.0)
    return 360.0 + math.degrees(theta)
```

Comment: This worked to convert it to degrees with 0 as North, then I just have to convert to arithmetic degrees.

Comment: I converted from geographic degrees to artithmetic degrees using "(450 - !Geographic_Degrees!) % 360"

Answer (score 0):

I had a workaround to do this with a few conditions. it works and keeps the angle as you want between 0 and 180, transfering Geographic angles (Azimuth in this line of code) to your Arithmetric angle:

> if(450-Azimuth<180, 450-Azimuth, if(450-Azimuth>360, 450-Azimuth-360, 450-Azimuth-180))

Comment: I used an `if` block the first time I tried this, too, but the real answer is to reverse the sign, with an offset: arith_deg = 90-azimuth_deg. Changing the range is then just addition of i*360. Of course, the question includes radians, so the answer should address that.