# Converting aspect/direction raster from geographic degrees to arithmetic radians

Tags: qgis, raster, terrain, angles, rotate

I have a raster/grid representing e.g. terrain aspect or flow direction, coded in geographic degrees (0-360°, clockwise from the north). I would like to convert it in arithmetic radians (0-2π, counterclockwise from the east).

I have no issue with converting degrees to radians in a linear fashion, but how can I handle the rotation and direction change? I am looking at achieving this programmatically (R/Python) or through usual GIS (Arc/Q), although I am favoring using QGIS' raster calculator.

Comment: Please decide, which software you're working with and add the appropriate tag, thank you.

Comment: Edited per your request.

Comment: You can just multtipy the degree values by (pi/180). Just understand that the radians are clockwise from N, same as the degree angles. I don't see what you have to "handle" regarding rotation and direction.

Comment: My needs specifically require my radians file to be counterclockwise from the east - simply converting degrees to radians is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [GBG](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/35764/gbg). I might have some something poorly with your code as I did not get the expected result, but looking at [your answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348059/191535) to [pretty much the same question but the other way around](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348052/converting-radians-to-arithmetic-degrees) I was able to figure it out with minimal adaptation.

A one liner in QGIS' raster calculator would be:

```
2 * 3.14159265359 - (if("degrees" < 90, "degrees" + 270, "degrees" - 90) * 3.14159265359 / 180)
```

`degrees` being your `raster@band`.

Which roughly translated to pseudocode would be:

```
function degreesGeoCWtoRadiansArithmCCW(degreesGeoCW):
    degreesRotated = (degreesGeoCW - 90) % 360
    radians = degreesRotated * pi / 180
    radiansArithmCCW = 2 * pi - radians 

    return radiansArithmCCW
```

Answer (score 4):

The aspect tool in QGIS has an option to output your aspects in trigonometric angle.  This would give you 0 as due east, 180 as west, 90 as south, and 270 as north.  Then just multiply the result by pi/180 to convert to theta.

[image]

I see QGIS 3.22 now has an IF available in the raster calculator (but I do not have experience working with IF statements in the QGIS raster calculator).  [See this link](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator) for using If statements.   If you do not have access to the original surface for input into a new Aspect calculation you could
adapt this Python code to give you theta counter-clockwise from east.

```
def TrueNorthAzimuthToUnitCircleRadians(degrees):
    '''degrees in north 0 clockwise to unit circle radians'''
    import math
    if degrees > 0 and degrees < 180:
        degrees = degrees + 180
    elif degrees > 180 and degrees <=359:
        degrees = degrees - 180
    elif degrees ==  360:
        degrees = 0
    theta = degrees * math.pi/180.0
    return theta
```